# Odoo and Qweb: render HTML in quotation report

Tags: html, odoo, qweb

I would like to be able to print quotations's payment terms in HTML in Odoo.

I edited the sale.order.form view, adding the widget="html" attribut to the term element like this:

```
<field name="note" widget="html" placeholder="Setup default terms and conditions in your company settings."/>
```

Now I can use the HTML editor when a create or edit a quote.

Then I edited the quotation report to render that HTML, using t-raw:

```
<p t-if="doc.payment_term_id.note">
    <span t-raw="doc.payment_term_id.note"/>
 </p>
```

But it doesn't work. When I print my quotation, the HTML generated from the HTML widget is escape and It prints the HTML elements like

or  in the terms.

Did I use t-raw in a bad way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

t-raw works as you expect. You did not edit the right field in your sale.order.form (or you changed the wrong line in your template).

Doing `<field name="note" widget="html" placeholder="Setup default terms and conditions in your company settings."/>` then changing the Qweb template to `<p t-raw="doc.note"/>` produces the expected change.

In your template you are changing another field (doc.payment_term_id.note which is not the same as doc.note).

Comment: That's it! So do you know what doc.payment_term_id.note is about?

Comment: doc.payment_term_id.note is a text that would explain to the person reading the document what does its payment term induce. The doc.note is just a text that would be used to save something about the document itself. Example in note : this customer is not trustworthy. Example in payment_term_id.note : You will have to pay 50% of the bill right away, and the remainder in 6 months after the bill is emitted.